# Graph and diagramming library

Tags: graph, 2d, workflow, diagram

I'm looking for a graph and diagramming library that can create workflow diagrams like the images below. The most important feature i'm looking for is the ability to create blocks/containers with ports (inputs/outputs) and the ability to create connections between them.

Ideally a library for OS X / Linux, but JS, SVG and Windows libs may also be applicable.

---

[image: Azure Media Services Premium Encoding Workflow Designer]
[image: Loxone Config]

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with the TeX/LaTeX environment, then try the package [tikz](http://www.texample.net/tikz/).

> TikZ and PGF are TeX packages for creating graphics programmatically. TikZ is build on top of PGF and allows you to create sophisticated graphics in a rather intuitive and easy manner.

For support and examples look around at the sister site [TeX.SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tikz-pgf).

Answer (score 0):

There are many different diagramming libraries out there for all kinds of platforms and languages (see the related section next to your question on the right).

If you are looking for more complex/technical visualizations many of the simpler ones are not flexible or powerful enough, though. IMHO for this kind of diagram you will probably need to look for a commercial library, especially if you want a diagram like the above one to be laid out automatically from your data and not just arranged manually by the user.

The [yFiles](http://www.yworks.com/yfiles) diagramming product family should be able to support your use-case. It offers:

- Built in support for ports - edges connect to ports which are owned by nodes (and edges optionally)
- Automatic arrangement of nodes and routing of edges for diagrams like in your example (hierarchic/sugiyama style layout)
- You can customize the look and the feel of the application and the items according to your exact requirements
- Available for java (Swing and JavaFX), .net (Windows Forms and WPF), and HTML5 (SVG and Canvas) and more

*Disclaimer*: The yFiles diagramming libraries are a commercial offering with paid updates and support options, created by yWorks, the company that I work for. I don't represent my employer on SO, though. This post is my own and represents my own opinion.